# Loading craftyjs with requirejs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, requirejs, craftyjs

The solution to this is probably very simple, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. How do you load [Craftyjs](http://craftyjs.com/) using [Requirejs?](http://requirejs.org/). I've tried loading it the normal why but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a change in the last version of crafty that [turned out to conflict](https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/pull/667) with using requirejs.

It should be fixed in the [0.6.2](https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/releases/tag/0.6.2) release.  Sorry you ran into this!